# Clipless Pedals Brand Identification

Tags: clipless, pedals-clipless

I purchased a set of used clipless pedals. They are somewhat unique in that they do not use a spring mechanism, but instead have a rubber block / set screw to provide tension. The problem is even with the screw completely backed out, the pedals are still nearly impossible to get out of (I've actually had to remove the shoe because I couldn't unclip).  I'd like to replace the rubber (I read that this was a problem with some Onzo pedals with a similar design), but I don't know the brand. The dust caps just say 'CM'.

[image]

Can anyone identify the brand, maker or supplier for me?

Comment: Well, they look to be SPD compatible.

Comment: It seems to me that whether they use a spring or rubber block they should still release the same way.  I suspect that most problems with releasing on SPDs are due to not having the shoe cleats aligned properly or simply not having them screwed on tight enough.

Comment: Did you try them on the bike itself? I find that releases can be tough to do if you're doing them "free hand" (i.e., pedal not on the bike and shoe off the foot) but your foot has much greater leverage, especially when you have the mass of the bike to work off of.

Comment: If they don't stamp a brand and a model I seriously doubt you are going to find parts.

Comment: Note that the platform/clipless combo you have there can create problems with some shoes when the lugs of the shoes catch on the platform.  (Also note that you're missing a part on the left pedal in the picture.)

Comment: I did try the pedals on the bike and nearly fell over for not being able to unclip.  Also, I removed the small black cover to show the rubber block (though it's not that great a photo). The cleats I have did not come with the pedals, but I'm pretty sure the pedals are SPD compatible.

Answer (score 3):

I have two pairs of shoes with different cleats - and two bikes with different pedals. Both pairs of shoes work well on one bike, but with one set of shoes the cleats jam on the other bike.  There are several brands of pedals and cleats that have varying degrees of compatibility. Replacing the rubber is unlikely to fix the problem of the cleat not releasing.

On top of this, there is also single release (Shimano SH51 and SH52) and multi release cleats (SH55 and SH56) cleats -  Single release will let you unclip with a horizontal rotation only, where as multi release let you unclip with a diagonal, horizontal or upwards pull.

Check you cleats - if they are single release, I would replace them with multi release as a first step. You may end up needing to try several different cleats, so a trip to the LBS might be the quickest way to find something that works.

From [SPD / SPD-R / SPD-SL cleat application table](http://www.stilen.com/bike_stuff/SPD-SPD-R_SPD_SL_cleats.pdf) :

- SM-SH51 for single direction release,and for “Easy step-in” feature
- SM-SH52 for PD-M858 and other SPD pedals except PD-7410 or PD-6500
- SM-SH55 for multi-directional release except PD-M959 / M540 / M520
- SM-SH56 SPD Cleat Sets Multi-directional release for PD-M959 / M540 /
  M520

Wellgo also do cleats that some claim are Shimano compatible, but other's say can be hard to get out of some Shimano pedals. They come in 98A (common), 99A and also I have seen a TB51A (but its not in the catalogue). Crank Bros and Richey have cleats that look similar, no idea about compatibility.

Comment: One thing that's different about the rubber block on those is the *width* of it compared to the usual spring mechanism.  The tread of my (walkable) shoes would probably hit the rubber before I could unclip.  In that case replacing the rubber might help but it wouldn't be an easy job. SH55/56s might help as well.  I reckon with my shoes and cleat position I could twist my heel inwards rather than outwards and not bump the rubber with the tread -- something else worth trying.

Comment: This is interesting; I knew there were cleats with different float, but didn't realize how many different options there are. Perhaps the cleats I have are just incompatible.